# What is this odd tool used for?

Tags: equipment

What is this tool I found at the thrift store in the kitchen section?

[image][image]

Comment: Are those holes on the corners? Possibly for mounting? I wonder if it is part of a bigger tool. Or possibly a handle.

Comment: No there are pads on the bottom. Ill add a pic.

Comment: Actually there are holes and the pads are on top of them,  probably added  and not part of the original. Also that middle thing rotates freely.

Comment: Yes, a wall mounted pie crust sealer. ????

Comment: You have my curiosity.  I upvoted the question.

Comment: So the only evidence that it’s kitchen related is what someone at the thrift store thought? Did you ask the staff?

Comment: Table top forearm massager? For after a long day of kneading bread dough... Someone please let us know!

Comment: Where are you? There isn't even a country in your bio.  As none of us has seen something like this before, it must be quite uncommon, but maybe knowing where you are would help narrow it down. Also is the middle part (roller) removable? It looks like it might be from the assymetry

Comment: Patent pending is a common US term. It's too bad they didn't wait for a number. That'd tell us.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger it took me a few years to get the joke of [Prof Pat Pending's](http://wackyraces.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_Pat_Pending) name in Wacky Races.

Comment: There is also the possibility that it isn't an anything. Sometimes well meaning people put together bits that look as though they belong together but don't really. I've seen videos of people trying to work out the function of junk shop finds that clearly aren't things so much as assemblages of stuff that could be made to go together and still spin/crank/slide whatever.

Comment: I mean it says patent pending... it might not even have made it to production. Just removing the kitchen context, it looks like it could very well fit a toilet paper roll

Comment: @aug if you look at the side view there is no significant clearance between the roller and the mounting surface.

Comment: @Spagirl ah blast you're right... I can see now why this is such a highly upvoted question. If you don't consider all the dimensions of the object, you really can't pinpoint what this tool is used for. I refuse to believe there isn't a reason for it's existence though.

Comment: @Spagirl From one view it looks like it can be mounted. From the other, it looks like it has 'feet'.

Comment: @ChrisH I think you may be onto something re the roller being removable. Not only the asymmetry, but the difference in how the ends of the roller look.

Comment: @Cindy If you look higher up this comment thread that's addressed. it has holes at the corners but pads have been put over them and are probably not original.

Answer (score 15):

Following Lorel C's idea, I searched a bit for "patent" "kientz" and "foot massager", and found the patent for this device - https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3b/09/3c/f580058fba56fc/USD243557.pdf

Short answer - yes, it's a foot massager.

Comment: whoahh! 1976?! - for reals?  I was imagining more like 1930s or -40s!

Answer (score 7):

If it is kitchenware, it's got to have an obscure decorative function, or else someone would have figured out the use by now, and it would not have obvious features designed for stationary use (the pads mentioned by NaniBly).

I say, not kitchen at all, but foot massager. It sits on the ground stationary, and you run your tired feet over it. (Assymmetry makes it more versatile for a variety of foot types.) Something like this: [image: footmassager]

For sale at [Gearbest](https://www.gearbest.com/massage-relaxation/pp_1488996.html). No I am not affiliated with them.

Comment: I wonder if it was originally something like a towel holder that someone has repurposed to sit flat (maybe as a foot massager)

Comment: @ChrisH but why would a towel holder have that asymmetry which would make a towel more likely to bunch up and stay damp? What would make that ‘de luxe’?

Comment: @Spagirl I wasn't convinced by my own suggestion, it was just an example. But I wouldn't read too much into "de luxe" given that it appears on all sorts of everyday items

Comment: Also, a lot of effort was put into the make-up of the roller part. Looks like 2 halves glued-together painted wood (?). Not great for kitchen around food where it will get dirty & soaking wet. If the rest of the item was molded of metal, why not just go ahead and make the roller that same way? ... Feels better on your foot than cold hard metal.

Comment: @LorelC.I was interpreting the line that you are seeing as a joint as a line of [flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(manufacturing)) from a moulding process, and reading the material as an old school dense rubber material.

Answer (score 1):

Pastry fluting tool ... it could also be a meat tenderizer, I used to have something similar back in the late 50's that i used to roll back and forth over lower grade meat cuts to break the fibers down, not like the pounding ones that cut the meats.  You could use it to flatten them for rolled meat recipes too.

Comment: Can you describe how you imagine it being mounted or held to carry out these functions?